# Accessing this object in componentdidmount

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem with accessing/triggering functions from `componentDidMount` in React. All `this` references seem to be undefined even if I try binding the method in the constructor like this:
`this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);`

Here is a part of the code; I'm accessing events on leaflet maps and printing map boundaries to the console - which works fine (and that's the reason I need to use `componentDidMount`)

```js
componentDidMount(){
  let mapInst =  this.refs.map.leafletElement;
  mapInst.on('moveend', function () {
    console.log(mapInst.getBounds())
  });

  mapInst.on('dragend', function () {
    console.log(mapInst.getBounds())
  });
}
```

Now I would like to pass those boundaries to state parameters or launch a function on callback to a parent element.

```js
updateParent = (newBounds) => {
  this.props.parentCallback({'bounds': newBounds});
}
```

However whatever construction I try, any function in higher scope is always undefined. It seems I cannot access neither `updateParent(mapInst.getBounds())` nor `this.updateParent(mapInst.getBounds())` from within `componentDidMount`.

Does anybody have any idea what the optimal construction in such cases is?

Full code for reference: https://pastebin.com/gQqazSCs

Comment: make callback function of mapInst.on to arrow function and then try to access updateParent like this

  mapInst.on('moveend', ()=> {
    this.updateParent(mapInst.getBounds())
  });

Arrow function will take its surrounding this

Comment: Is the error actually that `this` is undefined, or is it possibly the `refs` that is undefined. I find it **highly** unlikely that `this` would be undefined in a javascript class, especially a react Component.

Comment: Thank you @bajran this solved my issue :)

Comment: @Misiek i will answer that question can you please upvote it, It would be very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use leaflet's [whenReady](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-whenready) callback.

```
  handleMapReady = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ leafletMapElt: target });
  };
  ...
  <Map whenReady={this.handleMapReady}>...</Map>
```

I don't think the map is guaranteed to be in a "ready" state in componentDidMount

Comment: Hi JBC, I do not have a problem with accessing the values from the map, so the map is initialized properly and I have all boundaries in the console.logs as expected. The problem is that within the function componentDidMount I cannot seem to access or launch any function that would update my parent component with new values.

Answer (score 0):

Make callback function of mapInst.on to arrow function and then try to access updateParent like this `mapInst.on('moveend', ()=> { this.updateParent(mapInst.getBounds()) });`

Arrow function will take its surrounding this